# Why the Google Analytics API for PHP ignore dates before 2017-11-05

Tags: php, google-analytics

Using the API (v. 2) of Google Services I created PHP code for manage the total page views into my site, but the values are wrong.

For example, in one page I have 61,883 views as you can see into the image taked from Google Analytics:

[image]

But, with the API code I'm having about 10,000 views.

This is my code:

```
$optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'ga:pageTitle,ga:pagePath',
    'filters' => 'ga:hostname==www.my-domain.com',
    'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
    'start-index'=>1,
);

$res= $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $profileId,
    '2013-01-01',
    'today',
    'ga:pageviews',
    $optParams);
$rows=$res["rows"];
print_r($rows);
```

If I change the `today` param for another date before `2017-11-05` I'm having empty result, for example:

```
$optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'ga:pageTitle,ga:pagePath',
    'filters' => 'ga:hostname==www.my-domain.com',
    'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
    'start-index'=>1,
);

$res= $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $profileId,
    '2013-01-01',
    '2017-11-02',
    'ga:pageviews',
    $optParams);
$rows=$res["rows"];
print_r($rows);
```

If I write one date as `2017-12-05` I have very small value from page views, then I think the API begin count the views after `2017-11-05`.

It's a know bug of the API? How I can solve this issue?

Comment: You might need to contact the Google Analytics team. The code apparently works for the recent results, so you'll have to ask them why you can't get the historical data properly.

Comment: Thanks @aynber [I opened one issue into Github project](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1772). Wait and see.

Comment: you are not analysing on the same thing.   You cant look at a report in the website and the only query part of the dimensions in metrics that are listed and expect the same results.  YOu are analyzing on two different things.

Comment: @DaImTo I don't understand your comment? It's not the correct way to get the pageviews between two dates?

Comment: $res= $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $profileId,
    '2013-01-01',
    '2017-11-02',
    'ga:pageviews',
    $optParams);  That will get you the page views between two dates.   But there is no report on the google analytics website that only returns page views between two dates.  Unless you are creating custom reports which your image does not show.

Comment: @DaImTo it returns nothing, because the API ignores dates before `2017-11-05`. I don't know if my question is not clair, sorry, my english is very bad.

Comment: then you have the wrong profile id.

Comment: The profile id i'm using is the first profile: `$profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);`, the same I'm using from the GA site to obtain the data showed into the image.